# How to judge the VerticalGridView has scrolled to bottom in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an App for Android TV via Nexus Player. In my App, I use the `VerticalGridFragment` to show TV shows. For shows' number is 2000+, I want  to use page loading when the VerticalGridView scrolls to its bottom.

However, I get stuck on how to judge the VerticalGridView  has scrolled to bottom.
I use reflect to get the `VerticalGridView`,and `addScrollListener()` to it.Here the codes:

```
   private void addGridScrollListener() {
        try {
            Class<VerticalGridFragment> VerticalGridFragmentClass = VerticalGridFragment.class;
            Field verticalGridViewHolder = VerticalGridFragmentClass.getDeclaredField("mGridViewHolder");
            verticalGridViewHolder.setAccessible(true);
            VerticalGridPresenter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (VerticalGridPresenter.ViewHolder) verticalGridViewHolder.get(this);
            VerticalGridView gridView = viewHolder.getGridView();
            gridView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    };
```

`RecyclerView` doesn't has the function such as `getLastVisiableItemPosition`, so I can't know if the `VerticalGridView` has scrolled to bottom or not.

What should I do in the scrollListener ? Or is there any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
  private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            return;
        }

        //get current last child View
        View lastChildView = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount() - 1);
        //get the bottom
        int lastChildBottom = lastChildView.getBottom();
        // get recyclerView's bottom
        int recyclerBottom = recyclerView.getBottom() - recyclerView.getPaddingBottom();
        //get last childview's position
        int lastPosition = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getPosition(lastChildView);


        if (lastChildBottom == recyclerBottom && lastPosition == recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount() - 1) {
            // yes to bottom.
        }
    }
};
```